# When using KV in logstash, I am getting my key with escaped character, how do i read this value in the Ruby?

Tags: ruby, apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack

I have data coming from Kafka, and the data will look like this:

```
   "x-vcap-request-id":"smitshah",
   "x-cf-applicationid":"test",
   "x-cf-instanceid":"test2",
   "sec-ch-ua":"\"something\";\"willwork\""
```

It is similiar to JSON but it is not. So i thought of using KV filter,

```
kv {
 source => "header_v1"
value_split => ":"
field_split => ","
}
```

But now i am getting key this way:

[image]

So when i do `event.get('\"x-vcap-request-id\"')` i am getting empty result.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: `event.keys` will give list of keys. use them -)) 
check the client lib that you are using and look if there are options to symbolize/normalize/escape strategy for  such cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was either straightforward or I may have overlooked it, here is my solution:

Added `remove_char_key` and escaped `\` character, and it solved the problem:

```
kv {
        remove_char_key => "\""
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about Kafka but what your screenshoys shows is in Ruby a Hash (map) although only the keys are visible on the image.
In Ruby, if the name of the Hash is event (I'm guessing here) then you can get to the value of the x-vcap-request-id key like this `event["x-vcap-request-id"]`

I use a string as key because your screeenshot suggests it is but in Ruby keys are most of the time Symbols (a kind of unique fixed string) so it could also be `event[:x-vcap-request-id]`

Comment: Thanks. However when i do `event["x-vcap-request-id"]` it says `[]` not identified. It could be a logstash issue.